# Can't detect a memory leak

Tags: c, valgrind

I wrote a program to search for the longest sentence in several text files:

```
/* lngst_sentence_file_competition.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum consts {
    str_len = 5
};

typedef struct tag_item {
    int sentence_length;
    char *sentence;
    struct tag_item *next;
} item;

void free_str_if_it_is_not_lngst(
    char **str, char **lngst_file_str, int *curr_sentence_len,
    int *file_lngst_sentence_len
)
{
    if (*curr_sentence_len <= *file_lngst_sentence_len)
        free(*str);
    else {
        if (*lngst_file_str) {
            free(*lngst_file_str);
            *lngst_file_str = NULL;
        }
        *lngst_file_str = *str;
        *file_lngst_sentence_len = *curr_sentence_len;
    }
    *curr_sentence_len = 0;
    *str = NULL;
}

void find_lngst_sentence_in_next_file(
    FILE *file, char **lngst_file_str, int *lngst_sentence_len
)
{
    char *str = malloc(str_len*sizeof(char));
    int str_mem_size = str_len;
    int c;
    int curr_sentence_len = 0;
    int file_lngst_sentence_len = 0;
    while ((c=fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
            case '.':
                str[curr_sentence_len] = '.';
                str[curr_sentence_len + 1] = '\0';
                free_str_if_it_is_not_lngst(
                    &str, lngst_file_str, &curr_sentence_len,
                    &file_lngst_sentence_len
                );
                str = malloc(str_len*sizeof(char));
                str_mem_size = str_len;
                /* falls through */
            case '\n':
            case '\t':
                continue;
        }
        curr_sentence_len++;
        if (curr_sentence_len+1 == str_mem_size) {
            str = realloc(str, str_mem_size + str_len);
            str_mem_size += str_len;
        }
        str[curr_sentence_len - 1] = c;
    }
    free_str_if_it_is_not_lngst(
        &str, lngst_file_str, &curr_sentence_len, &file_lngst_sentence_len
    );
    if (*lngst_sentence_len < file_lngst_sentence_len)
        *lngst_sentence_len = file_lngst_sentence_len;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *file;
    item *first = NULL;
    int lngst_sentence_len = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=1; i < argc; i++) {
        char *str = NULL;
        file = fopen(argv[i], "r");
        if (!file) {
            perror(argv[i]);
            exit(1);
        }
        find_lngst_sentence_in_next_file(file, &str, &lngst_sentence_len);
        printf("%s\nString length is %d.\n", str, lngst_sentence_len);
        /* add_new_element_to_linked_list(&first, str); */
    }
    /* print_sentences(first); */
    return 0;
}
```

I also wrote a small test file `test.txt`:

```
a.
ab.
abc.
```

I ran my program using Valgrind:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full -s ./lngst_sentence_file_competition test.txt
```

Valgrind produced the following output:

```
==359271== 
abc.
String length is 3.
==359271== 
==359271== HEAP SUMMARY:
==359271==     in use at exit: 477 bytes in 2 blocks
==359271==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 5 frees, 5,612 bytes allocated
==359271== 
==359271== 5 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==359271==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==359271==    by 0x109389: find_lngst_sentence_in_next_file (lngst_sentence_file_competition.c:53)
==359271==    by 0x1094F4: main (lngst_sentence_file_competition.c:87)
==359271== 
==359271== LEAK SUMMARY:
==359271==    definitely lost: 5 bytes in 1 blocks
==359271==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==359271==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==359271==    still reachable: 472 bytes in 1 blocks
==359271==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==359271== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==359271== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==359271== 
==359271== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Can anyone see the source of the memory leak?

In my opinion, I've correctly freed all the allocated memory.

Comment: Maybe the longest string - which is an output of the function - is not freed?  (just using the name of the function as a guide).  You'd have to free it in main.

Comment: Memcheck told you it is at `==359271==    by 0x109389: find_lngst_sentence_in_next_file (lngst_sentence_file_competition.c:53)`

Comment: And you also have 472 bytes still reachable. Memcheck suggested that you rerun with `--show-leak-kinds=all`.

Comment: @Computable Thanks :) This helped me fix the `definitely lost: 5 bytes in 1 blocks` bug. Although I don't quite understand why Valgrind marked it as `definitely lost` if the `first` was pointing pointed to the data at the end of the program's work.

Comment: @Computable @PaulFloyd It's interesting that even if I add `free(str);` as the line 90 (the very end of the `for` cycle in the `main` function) even then Valgrind shows that I have `HEAP SUMMARY:  in use at exit: 472 bytes in 1 blocks total heap usage: 7 allocs, 6 frees, 5,612 bytes allocated`. If we use GDB and set breakpoints at all the `malloc`s and `free`s functions we'll see that in reality we have 4 allocs and 4 frees respectively. Also I don't have any idea how I can possibly have 472 bytes in 1 blocks left if all my mallocs allocate only 5 bytes of memory :/

Comment: You have an `fopen` which you do not `fclose` - the `fopen` in all likelihood is allocating memory for the `FILE` block - and naturally one would expect it to be freed when closed properly.  You should add this inside the loop at the end since you handle multiple files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your total usage heap you have 7 allocs and 5 frees, the last two remaining are related to the file pointer **file** and the **str** pointer.

At the beginning of for loop you define a char pointer as null, after finishing for loop there will still be a pointer that is not being used, therefore, place a free(str) after printf(), this way with each new interaction you will allocate and deallocate this memory space. Furthermore, close the file pointer as this detaches the memory space used to read it.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        FILE *file;
        item *first = NULL;
        int lngst_sentence_len = 0;
        int i;
        for (i=1; i < argc; i++) {
            char *str = NULL;
            file = fopen(argv[i], "r");
            if (!file) {
                perror(argv[i]);
                exit(1);
            }
            find_lngst_sentence_in_next_file(file, &str, &lngst_sentence_len);
            printf("%s\nString length is %d.\n", str, lngst_sentence_len);
            /* add_new_element_to_linked_list(&first, str); */
            free(str);
            fclose(file);
        }
        /* print_sentences(first); */
        return 0;
    }
```